# Libgit2 git_diff_line_t does not supports line modify instead it uses addition and deletion, any way to detect?

Tags: c, git, diff, libgit2

I am trying to see which lines are modified in a diff, but libgit2 API has only the line types:-

```
GIT_DIFF_LINE_ADDITION
GIT_DIFF_LINE_DELETION
```

And if we want to detect modification there needs to be some workaround.

I observed that whenever there is modification the lines tend to delete in a sequence and then they start addition. But this sequence is not always valid. So not sure what can be right pseudocode / algorithm to detect this.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/gaurav1999/diferencia/merge_requests/3/diffs

I am trying to do this in VALA.
But any algorithm suggestions will help in any language even English.

For this case it passes:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/gaurav1999/diferencia/merge_requests/3#note_544291

For this case it fails and perhaps others also it will do.
https://gitlab.gnome.org/gaurav1999/diferencia/merge_requests/3#note_544294

Comment: Git diffs fundamentally have no concept of *modification*, all they do is record insertions and deletions, as you noticed. This occasionally leads to “wrong” diffs that clearly don’t represent the actual series of edits (of course this doesn’t matter for the outcome). If you want to find modified lines you need to develop your own heuristic. I say heuristic because it won’t always work.